# How to count occurrence in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, count, aggregate-functions

I have a list of items (e.g. shirts, tops, pants, adidas, nike, puma etc.) and years in a format like this 2017-01-01. I want to find out how many times each item was purchased per year and have it arranged by year.

How can I do this?

I have the following table called Items:

```
Year | Purchases | 
------------------
2017-01-01 | makeup
2018-01-01 | clothing
2019-01-01 | makeup
2017-01-01 | shoes
2017-01-01 | clothing
2016-01-01 | shoes
2018-01-01 | clothing
2017-01-01 | clothing
2019-01-01 | makeup
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
Year | Purchases| Count
-----------------------
2016 | Shoes    |  1
2017 | Makeup   |  1
2017 | Clothing |  2
2017 | Shoes    |  1
2018 | Clothing |  2
2019 | Makeup   |  2
```

My code so far is this:

```
SELECT YEAR(d.date_format) AS Year
      , Purchase = (CASE WHEN it.type IN ('shirts', 'tops', 'pants) THEN 'clothing'
                     WHEN it.type('nike','adidas', 'puma') THEN 'shoes'
                     WHEN it.type('facewash', 'lipstick') THEN 'makeup' END), COUNT(*)
FROM ....
    INNER JOIN...
WHERE...
GROUP BY Year, Purchase
ORDER BY Year
```

Comment: The answers given below should work already, unless you are doing it wrong. Can you edit the post and show all the tables being used in your query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT YEAR(d.date_format) AS Year,
       (CASE WHEN it.type IN ('shirts', 'tops', 'pants') THEN 'clothing'
             WHEN it.type IN ('nike','adidas', 'puma') THEN 'shoes'
             WHEN it.type IN ('facewash', 'lipstick') THEN 'makeup'
        END), COUNT(*)
FROM .... INNER JOIN...
WHERE...
GROUP BY YEAR(d.date_format),
         (CASE WHEN it.type IN ('shirts', 'tops', 'pants') THEN 'clothing'
               WHEN it.type IN ('nike','adidas', 'puma') THEN 'shoes'
               WHEN it.type IN ('facewash', 'lipstick') THEN 'makeup'
          END)
ORDER BY Year;
```

The use of `=` in the `SELECT` suggests that you are using SQL Server.  SQL Server does not support the use of aliases in the `GROUP BY`, so you need to repeat the expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
select year, purchases, count(*)
from table
group by year, purchase
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Hi! Could you check my updated post? I get an error saying "Invalid column name 'Year'" and the same error for the purchase column when i try to do count(*)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `group by` with `order by`

```
select year, purchases, count(*) 
from myTable
group by year, purchases
order by year
```

Comment: Hi! Could you check my updated post? I get an error saying "Invalid column name 'Year'" and the same error for the purchase column when i try to do count(*)